# Cancel (delete) notification with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have implemented a scheduled notification feature in my app. How do I cancel a notification completely before it appears?
Thank you!

Comment: You can use the same `notification_id ` you used while you are creating the notification to cancel it using the `NotificationManager`

Answer (score -1):

> How do I cancel a notification ?

Use [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) from the NotificationManager with the ID you originally passed to [notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Comment: Cancel for me will clear it from the notification bar, but I want to remove it completely before it shows...

Comment: You haven't provided any information to suggest how you have "scheduled" the notification, so I can only guess that you are using an AlarmManager. "Unschedule" the Notification with [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) from AlarmManager.

Comment: If that doesn't help, simply check if the Notification should be displayed before you call `notify()`.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I seem to have this problem solved. I hade to make sure my intent was the same intent as I was calling.

Comment: Sounds like you used `cancel()` from the AlarmManager. You have to be precise when working with PendingIntents, the documentation even acknowledges [it can be tricky.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)